# Записать полученный ответ в формате JSON в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем привет. Есть сайт на Wordpres. Есть поставщик, у него есть свое API. Передача данных осуществляется по протоколу HTTP. Применяются принципы REST API. Сервер отвечает в формате JSON.
Пишу скрипт, который добавляет товары и в дальнейшем будет обновлять товары. На данный момент скрипт умеет подключаться к API поставщика, проходить авторизацию, делать запрос и получать ответ и записывать его в файл. Но в php я новичек, столкнулся с такой проблемой: Как записать полученные данные в БД? Записывать нужно только некоторые поля. Какой должен быть порядок действий? Или может есть ссылки что почитать по данному вопросу?

Comment: https://www.hostinger.ru/rukovodstva/zapis-v-bazu-dannyh-mysql-php-kod/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

`$a = json_decode($text);`

$a = array

$a[key]..

Выбираете нужное и сохраняете в БД